# Change angular-materials md-tooltip text dynamically through controller

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, coffeescript

I am rendering the following HTML which introduces a tooltip by Angular-Material and an input-field which gets initialized as DatePicker.

```
- content_for :top_datepicker do
  .toolbar-icons
    md-tooltip md-direction="bottom" initial text
    input#range-picker.dashboard-daterange-picker.no-margin[type="text"
      placeholder="#{@start_date.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")} - #{@end_date.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")}"
    ]
```

As you can see it is inside a `content_for` block by Rails and gets rendered outside the corresponding controller.
Due to the nature of the current state the application is in, we have to handle it like this.

Inside our Angular-Controller we want to change the text of this tooltip based on certain conditions. We further use jQuery to manipulate the respective part of the DOM.

The following represents how the above code will render in HTML:

```
<div class="toolbar-icons" aria-label="perf.data is DISABLED">
    <input class="dashboard-daterange-picker no-margin" id="range-picker" placeholder="21.10.2015 - 11.10.2016" type="text" disabled="">
</div>
```

The following code gets called to ultimately manipulate the tooltip:

```
updateDatePicker = ->
  el = $scope.el
  isDisabled = $scope.isDisabled()

  if isDisabled
    el.parent().attr("aria-label", "DISABLED")
    el.prop('disabled', true)
  else
    el.parent().attr("aria-label", "ENABLED")
    el.prop('disabled', false)
```

Unfortunately the change does not have an effect on the tooltips text. While the `aria-label` is getting changed, the text displayed is not.

If you have any input on this, it'd be highly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Controllers should never have any DOM code in it ... use angular data binding

Comment: I am well aware of that. Unfortunately this is not possible for the reason described in my question.

Comment: So how does *"gets rendered outside controller"* work? When you render outside are you using script tag templating?

Comment: Provide a [mcve] that can be executed in browser

Comment: This is based on a concept of Ruby on Rails. At point 1 you have the option to describe where content gets inserted at. Point 2 describes what content to use (Point 2 is the block of code you can see here). Point 1, in the current state of the app, is located somewhere else inside the definition of our navigation. Yet the Angular-Controller gets called a lot later down the road and causes the, through "content_for" added part, not to have any access to the controllers scope.

Comment: Why does rails need to do all this at all? Why can't you use standard html ? If for whatever strange reason you need to do it that way you can create directives and put that markup in a script tag template and assign to the directive `template` property, then angular will render in correct scope

Comment: Or use `ng-include` and script tag template that is generated by your `content_for`. Or move controller higher in the hierarchy.

Comment: Moving the controller up in hierarchy is not an option. Using ng-include would still mean my actual set of html gets rendered outside of its controller but actually needs to access its scope synchronously. Could I render a directive outside a controller (but inside my ng-app) and give it access to a specific controller's scope?

Comment: Do you know what angular script tag templates are?